# How do we rewrite and evaluate this Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Consider an integral problem of the form:

$Fun(a, b)=\int_{1}^{\infty} F(a, b, x) \ G(a, b, x) \ dx$.

here $a, b$ are real numbers and by definition the value of $F(a, b, x)$  and $G(a, b, x)$ are well defined. Moreover, we are given only those values of $a, b$ where $Fun(a, b)$ converges.

We know how to calculate the value of $G(a, b, x)$ using algebraic means such that it can be integrated. But, it is simply **NOT KNOWN** how to write the definition of $F(a, b, x)$ that can be integrated (its certainly unknown).

Now, what I have managed to create are two functions $N(a, b, x)$ and $D(a, b, x)$ such that:

1. For all non integer values of $x$: $F(a, b, x)= \frac {N(a, b, x)}{D(a, b, x)}$
2. For all integer values of $x$: $F(a, b, x)= 0$, where as for integer values $N(a, b, x)=0$ and $D(a, b, x)=0$.

**Query:** Is it possible to rewrite the above integral as $Fun(a, b)=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac {N(a, b, x)}{D(a, b, x)} \ G(a, b, x) \ dx$ and solve it to calculate the value of $Fun(a, b)$.

The thought I have is for all the non integer values of $x$ the value in both cases will be the exactly the same and for integer cases $F(a, b, c)=0$ and $\frac {N(a, b, c)}{D(a, b, c)}=0/0$ or not defined. So the actual sum of non zero terms would be the same in both cases. Can this integral be solved/evaluated like this? If not can someone suggest a work around using ${N(a, b, c)}$ and ${D(a, b, c)}.$

I am not sure and struggling a bit. Can someone please help with this?

Just to reiterate, I want to calculate the exact value of $Fun(a, b)$ not some approximation or equivalent formulation that is again not known to be solvable.

Comment: This looks a lot like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @K.defaoite It would be an xy problem if I was not certain we DO NOT (I specifically wrote that in caps and bold!) know of ANY means to solve y (its a research level open problem). So as soon as I mentioned it people would wash their hands off it saying it cannot be done or its an open problem. thus i kept it abstract. But if details are needed $F(a, b, x)$ involves given the positive real number $x$ $F(a, b, x)$ returns the decimal part of $x$ (for the time being to simplify things we ignore $a$ and $b$). Eg: $F(11.1): .1$ and $F(11.0): 0$. Can you please comment?

Comment: Are the singularities in $F$ removable, or not? If they are not removable, your function is probably not integrable anyway. If they are, you can simply.... *remove* them.

Comment: What I mean, basically, is you have a function $F$ that is not defined at a finite number of points. So, why can't you just say $F(a,b,n)=0$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$? Changing the function at a finite number of points won't affect the integral.

Comment: @K.defaoite my background is not in professional mathematics. i just wanted to clarify that. Now, as i stated $F(a, b, x)$ is a function that is defined as: "Given a real number $x$ $F(x)$ returns its decimal part. If $x$ is an integer it outputs 0." Its a symbolic function and as far as I know we do not know how to mathematically create it. If its possible please let me know?? What I have done is to create something mathematically such that: $N(a, b, x)/D(a, b, x)$ gives the decimal part for all non integers but for integers its $0/0$. Can we use this to solve this integral somehow?

Comment: so the function $F():$ (definition described above) is as far as I know symbolic only, and $N()/D()$ outputs $0/0$ at every integer. Can we somehow use this fractional equivalent to solve this integral? or do we have a mathematical formulation of $F()$ that I can use?

Comment: Why didn't you say that $F$ returns the decimal part in the question? You can write simply $F(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: How do we implement the floor function so that it can be integrated for all values of x in the integral above?!

Comment: I don't see what the problem is.... The floor function is piecewise continuous, hence integrable.

Comment: Let us assume the above infinite series converges to a single value. What I understand you are suggesting is to have infinite series of terms for each sub interval.. but then we again would need the summation of this infinite series to get the final sum.. and we won't know how to do it.. so if i am correct it would transform one problem to another..

Comment: Once again, telling us the context of this problem would *really* help.